# How to set a value programatically only when a content type is saved for the first time?

Tags: hooks, 8

I'm trying to record the user agent string into a text field (`field_useragent`) the first time a content type is saved.  This is what I tried:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()
 */
function mymodule_node_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getType() == 'my_content_type') {
    // Log the user agent.
    $entity->set("field_useragent", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  }
}
```

But, this doesn't save the user agent string.  So I tried using this code:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()
 */
function mymodule_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getType() == 'my_content_type') {
    // Log the user agent.
    $entity->set("field_useragent", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);  }
}
```

This saves the user agent string, but it does so every time the node is edited.  How can I save it only upon insertion?

Comment: Have you tried to check, if the node id isset? I think the first time there will be no node id.

Comment: In the second case use $entity->isNew(). In the insert the documentation says "This hook runs once the entity has been stored.". So you're too late :)

Comment: Have you tried reacting to a "rule" when the content is saved?

Comment: @rrirower Alas, rules is unstable for D8 at this time.

Comment: See documentation for [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x). When using `hook_entity_insert`, the entity is already saved. This is why your update didn't seem to work. If you want to set a value on the entity, you'd need re-save the entity after setting, e.g. call `$entity->save();`.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Ivan Jaros comment:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()
 */
function mymodule_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getType() == 'my_content_type') {
    /// Log the user agent if the account is being created.
    if ($entity->isNew()) {
      $entity->set("field_useragent", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    }
  }
}
```